# What is the difference between BufRead and BufEnter?

Tags: vim

I am confused between the two events `BufRead` and `BufEnter`. What is the difference between them?

Some example scenarios where I would choose one over the other would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `:help BufRead` and `:help BufEnter`?

Comment: Yes. I read the doc. But I did not clearly understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A *buffer* is the in-memory representation of a file; to edit one, it has to be displayed in a *window*.

The `BufRead` event is triggered after Vim has read the file into its memory. Unless you reload via `:edit!`, this only happens once.

The `BufEnter` is fired whenever you activate a certain buffer, i.e. when it becomes the buffer the cursor is in. For example when you have split windows that show different buffers, and you move between then. Also in a single window, when you use a command like `<C-^>`, `:bnext` to change which buffer is currently edited.

Comment: I see many autocmds defined with `BufRead,BufEnter`. Why is `BufRead` also used, considering that `BufEnter` will always happen after it before you start editing the buffer?

Answer (score 4):

`BufRead` is triggered after the buffer has been populated with the content of a file.

`BufEnter` is triggered after you enter a buffer for editing.

You may use `BufNew`, `BufRead` or `BufAdd` if you want to do something upon the creation of the buffer: setting some global variable, populating a buffer list of your own for use in a script.

You may use `BufEnter` when you want to set specific options depending on the filetype or whatever.