# Automatically change colorscheme based on FileType

Tags: vim

I've read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129517/what-is-the-difference-between-bufread-and-bufenter)

I've also executed the following help topics:
`:h BufEnter`
`:h BufNewFile`
`:h BufLeave`

...but still - I have the following in `vimrc` - how does it work?

```
colo pyte
autocmd! BufEnter,BufNewFile *.sql colo Zenesque
autocmd! BufLeave  *.sql colo pyte
```

If I open a `.sql` file I assume that its executing `BufNewFile` and therefore applies the color scheme Zenesque? If I then leave that buffer and place the cursor in the buffer for vimrc then surely the `BufLeave` line will execute but which buffer does it apply pyte to, and why do I specify `.sql` next to `BufLeave`?

Comment: There must not be a space in the event list: `BufEnter, BufNewFile` should read `BufEnter,BufNewFile`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat - nice spot; there is no space in the actual file ....I typed the above - will edit now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colorschemes are global; their colors apply to all windows at the same time. Therefore, you can only create the *illusion* of different colorschemes per buffer / filetype / window, which will be shattered when you have different ones visible at the same time. If you don't use window splits or only ever have splits using the same colorscheme visible at the same time, your solution with `:autocmd` should work, though.

The `BufLeave` is the counterpart of `BufEnter`; the `BufNewFile` is just a special case for new buffers. All have the same `*.sql` pattern so that they undo each other. For example, when you move from your `.vimrc`, the `BufEnter` will execute. When you move back, the `BufLeave` will execute. For your `.vimrc` buffer, similar events will fire, but there's no action behind them, since you haven't defined similar autocmds for `*.vim`.

Note: If you want to extend your switching to more filetypes and colorschemes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153602/813602) may be helpful.