# In VIM how do I change the backbround color of just the QuickFix window?

Tags: vim

Subject says it all:  In VIM how do I change the backbround color of just the QuickFix window?  Something that can go in a script or the .vimrc.

Comment: I am bold to say: No Way. ;)

Comment: Also see [Automatically change colorscheme based on FileType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692581/automatically-change-colorscheme-based-on-filetype)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly, but you could cheat your way to it by using a colorcolumn at each column of text in that window. Of course, you also only get one global color for the colorcolumn, so that might not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use signs. If you place a sign on every single line in the quickfix window, you can set the background color of each sign to color the entire window. Since this is window-local, and the coloring will be incorrect if the number of lines increases, you will also need to re-process the signs on autocmds. WinEnter, QuickFixCmdPost, etc. may be helpful. You could store the number of lines in a window-local variable and check for that variable doesn't exist or doesn't match the lines in the buffer to determine whether to do an update.